# Insert stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a simple insert statement to save form details in PHP.

I want to convert this into store procedure.

Below is my current code how

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "aaaaaa";
    $password = "ppppp";
    $dbname = "xxxx_database";

    $sName = $_POST["name"];
    $sEmail = $_POST["email"];
    $sPhone = $_POST["Number"];
    $sInterest = $_POST["interest"];
    $Comments = $_POST["Inquiry"];


    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ContactForm (Name, Email, PhoneNumber,Interest,Comments) VALUES ('$sName',  '$sEmail', '$sPhone','$sInterest', '$Comments')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

$conn->close();
```

**And this is my Store procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER = `xxx`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SpInsertContactForm` ( IN `Name` TEXT CHARSET armscii8, IN `Email` TEXT CHARSET armscii8, IN `PhoneNumber` TEXT CHARSET armscii8, IN `Interest` TEXT CHARSET armscii8, IN `Comments` TEXT CHARSET armscii8 ) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER INSERT INTO ContactForm( Name, Email, PhoneNumber, Interest, Comments )
VALUES (
Name, Email, PhoneNumber, Interest, Comments
)
```

How can i use this store procedure. I am new to php and mysql need pointer in this.

I use SP as

```
if (!$mysqli->query("CALL SpInsertContactForm($sName,  $sEmail, $sPhone,$sInterest, $Comments)")) 
        {
            echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
        }
```

This doesn't save anything in DB

Answer (score 1):

you cal use this: `$mysqli->query("CALL SpInsertContactForm('<your_namevalue>','<your_emailvalue>','<your_phonevalue>','<your_interestvalue>','<your_commentvalue>')`

For more please follow the link:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: Do i need to close the connect as it is done. Do you mean i shoudl replace INSERT .... with your code snippet..

Comment: Yes.you can close the connection also.Please follow the link...it has an example also.

Comment: `if (!$conn->query("CALL SpInsertContactForm($sName,  $sEmail, $sPhone,$sInterest, $Comments)")) 
        {
            echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
        }` doesnt work

Comment: echo "CALL SpInsertContactForm($sName, $sEmail, $sPhone,$sInterest, $Comments)" this part & run it directly from mysql